# join/subquery in OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm updating a table and adding data on the changes using the TSQL OUTPUT clause. The problem is that the updated table only contains normalised IDs for the data I want to output and I need it in human readable form. Here's a simplified example to show what I mean

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION
(locationid INT, name VARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE USER
(userid INT, username VARCHAR(50), locationid INT)

--insert some test data

UPDATE USER
SET locationid = @somevalue
WHERE userid = @someothervalue
```

I know I can add something like

```
OUTPUT inserted.username
+ ' location changed from ' + deleted.locationid
+ ' to ' + inserted.locationid
```

but that's no use to the end user who wants to know the location name, not its database ID.
I tried replacing `deleted.locationid` with `(SELECT name from LOCATION WHERE locationid = deleted.locationid)`, and similarly for `inserted.locationid` and was met with the error `Subqueries are not allowed in the OUTPUT clause`

I've seen a couple of answers saying joins are allowed in OUTPUT clauses, but I haven't found a way to join separately on `inserted` and `deleted`. Is this possible in a single step in SQL Server 2008 R2, or will I need to do it via an intermediate step of storing the old and new values then joining in a second query for the output I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Microsoft article [Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177564.aspx) clearly describes the limitations of output clause in any DML operations like insert, update and delete.

It also describes that you can't use subquery with output clause

So here you can records the locationid from inserted and deleted row and in a table variable and can further get the location name using join with Location table

Example

```
INSERT INTO location VALUES(1,'Delhi')
INSERT INTO location VALUES(2,'Noida')


INSERT INTO [USER] VALUES(1,'Sandeep',1)

DECLARE  @result table(UserName varchar(50), OldLocationId Int,NewLocaionId Int)


UPDATE [USER] SET locationid=2
OUTPUT  INSERTED.UserName, DELETED.locationid,INSERTED.locationid INTO @result
WHERE userid=1

SELECT * FROM @result
```

Comment: OK, so it does need an intermediate step. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
OUTPUT inserted.username
+ ' location changed from ' + deleted.name + ' to ' + inserted.name
```

Comment: I'm not updating LOCATION so there is no inserted.name or deleted.name

Answer (score 0):

Union your join and delete into a subquery and join on it.